# Open bootstrap nav tab within an accordion by url

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have three tabs within an accordion on the profile page, I am trying to get these tabs to open from the home page by their respective url. This is what I have:

URL from the home page

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="Profile.html#collapseOne#house-tab"> House</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="Profile.html#collapseOne#shop-tab"> Shop</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="Profile.html#collapseOne#land-tab"> Land</a>
```

The Accordion and it's tab headings

```
    <div class="accordionLink shadow mb-5" id="accordion1">
     <div class="card z-depth-0">
      <div class="card-header text-center blue-grey lighten-5 rounded"  id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
    <button class="btn btn-link btn-lg" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" style="font-size: 18px;">
            Click to Register Property
     </button>
     </h5>
         </div>
         <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion1">
        <div class="card-body">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs md-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
         <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link active show" id="house-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#house" role="tab" aria-controls="home-ex"
                              aria-selected="true">Houses</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="shop-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#shop" role="tab" aria-controls="profile-ex" aria-selected="false">Shops</a>
            </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" id="land-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#land" role="tab" aria-controls="contact-ex" aria-selected="false">Lands</a>
           </li>
         </ul>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to refer each tab within an accordion (in the profile page) by URL from another page (Home page) such that the link opens the accordion and displays the user desired tab.